# Visual Studio 2015 RC1 - Manage Nuget packages for solution

Tags: visual-studio-2005, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When opening the Nuget Package Manager in VS2015RC1 on the **solution level** and filtering on installed/update available I get a list of all available packages within my solution.

But when I try to upgrade a package it has ALL projected within the solution selected by default which is not what I want since we have a large solution with many projects and I obviously don't want to add say JQuery to all of them.
And due to the large number of projects I cannot go through each and update the projects individually.

Anybody else having the same problem? Or am I missing something.

[image: Nuget screenshot]

EDIT:
There were no error, the ACTION dropdown need to be changed to Update instead of Install. Sorry about this guys.

Comment: What happens if you change the Action combobox value from install to Update/Upgrade? Wouldn that only highlight the relevant projects?

Comment: That was the solution, I changed the wrong dropdown box. So its only I that have misunderstood the UI.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Action combobox value from install to Update/Upgrade

[image]

Comment: God damn was that NOT intuitive at all. Thanks @kazuo, not so much Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to filter Update Available

I reported such issue which was fixed
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/806

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try the console? Type on the search "console" and open package manager console at the bottom and then click restore.

Comment: The restore functionality actually works so its only the Upgrade/Update feature that's problematic for me. Still no idea what causes the behavior.

Comment: that's strange, what is your nuget version?

Comment: I agree, the installed version is 3.0.60410.213 (NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug - We fixed this for RTM